# sql parameters error

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my cs code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString());

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update slab set salbn = @salbn,basic = @basic,hra = @hra,trvl = @trvl,mdeca = @mdeca,atnd = @atnd,tote = @tote where salbn = @salbn", con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@salbn", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salbn", TextBox21.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@basic", TextBox12.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hra", TextBox13.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trvl", TextBox15.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdeca", TextBox16.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atnd", TextBox18.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tote", TextBox20.Text);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        MsgBox("Updated Successfully");
}
```

I got error

> The variable name '@salbn' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. Must declare the scalar variable "@basic"

I am using C# and SQL Server

Comment: You `Add()` `@salbn` and then you call `AddWithValue()` for not-so-good measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just as it says: you are adding a parameter named `salbn` twice. Once just below `SqlCommand com = ...` and the second time on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

In your query you have two parameters with the same name `@salbn`. No problem, but you cannot add two times in the `Parameters` collection. I've seen your code have two controls for the same parameters, for change the name of one of them, for sample:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update slab set salbn = @salbnValue, basic = @basic, hra = @hra, trvl = @trvl, mdeca = @mdeca, atnd = @atnd, tote = @tote where salbn = @salbn", con);

com.Parameters.Add("@salbnValue", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salbn", TextBox21.Text);
```

Comment: It is fine to use the same parameter twice in the query (if that's what you want). What is wrong is to define it twice in the `Parameters` collection.

Comment: That said, looking at the OP code it seems that he really means to use two different parameters. Otherwise the `SET` code does not really make a lot of sense.